# Excel formula for merging rows

Tags: excel, merge

Consider the following four rows in a spreadsheet

```
AAA  VALUE   TAG
AAA  VALUE   TAG2
AAA  VALUE   TAG3
AAA  VALUE   TAG4
```

I want to be able to combine all four of these rows into a single row as follows:

```
AAA  VALUE    TAG,TAG2,TAG3,TAG4
```

Is this possible?

So far, I have found a formula that partially works.

=IF(A1=A2,C1&","&C2)

Which gives me the following:

```
AAA  VALUE   TAG    TAG,TAG2
AAA  VALUE   TAG2   TAG2,TAG3
AAA  VALUE   TAG3   TAG3,TAG4
AAA  VALUE   TAG4   FALSE
```

To make it more complicated, sometimes there are only 2 rows where column A matches, and sometimes there are 5 or more where column A matches.

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is in A:C starting in Row2 with labels in Row1, enter =C2 in E2 and:

in D2: `=IF(A2=A3,"",COUNTIF(A:A,A2))` and copy down
in E3: `=IF(A2=A3,E2&", "&C3,C3)` and copy down

then copy A:E to a new sheet and Paste Special Values there. Filter and select Blanks in ColumnD. Delete these and ColumnsC&D.